# meteor xss code tampering

Tags: security, xss, meteor

My main concern is the following :

- since meteor is based on JavaScript, it can be changed/tampered @ client side, so what happens if I change or create new collections and start to spam the db will it be only @ client side (memory only) or on both sides i.e: server side too.
- is user input is cleaned from xss before the save in the server side ?.

Comment: I'd also like to know this - I browsed the website for a bit and stopped short once I read that *everything* is done in js. Not that I have anything against that, but I just prefer at least a smidge of server-side security in order to sleep well at night.

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Everything is done in JS means" from a language point of view.  There is still separation of server vs client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a new collection on the client side, the server will have no knowledge of this and also will not create the necessary stuff to edit the database server side. The spammed data will only be in the client side memory.

```
Trees  = new Meteor.Collection("boom");
    Meteor.Collection
Trees.insert({hi:"hi"});
    "4b0d5ff2-058c-4041-849b-ce2e0d548160"
logging.js:30: insert failed: 404 -- Method not found
```

Comment: this is correct and to further clarify it has no knowledge because it has not subscribed. Unless you start to tamper with an existing subscribed collection there is nothing yet to stop this from happening.

Comment: so to prevent tempering with subscribed collection we should manage critical sections by locking down the database helper methods @ server side as shown in [brito](http://britto.co/blog/security_with_meteor)  
this should do the trick i guess :
    
`Meteor.startup(function () {  

  _.each([/**collections names **/], function(collection) {  

    _.each(['insert', 'update', 'remove'], function(method) {  

      Meteor.default_server.method_handlers['/' + collection + '/' + method] = function() {};  

    });  

  });  

});`  

  

Thanks all.